# can not have multiple base classes in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was Inherit my enemy class to it's base class and Interface in C# but it is show console error in unity I checked how to inherits base class and interface C# and I wrote code following them and error is not gone, my code is below.

interface ->

```
public interface IDamageble
{
    int Health { get; set; }
    void Damage();

}
```

one of enemy type ->

```
public class MossGiant : Enemy , IDamageble
{
    public int Health{get;set;}
    public void Damage()
    {
        //throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

in my unity console say ->
error CS1721: Class 'MossGiant' cannot have multiple base classes: 'Enemy' and 'IDamageble'

what is wrong here?

Comment: areyou sure `IDamageble` is an interface?

Comment: yes sir @daniel-a-white

Comment: right click it and go to the reference. try cleaning your project.

Comment: Your enemy class should be derived from idamageable and moss giant should be derived from enemy.

Comment: not working sir because Enemy class also inherits to MonoBehaviour class so I inherit IDamageble class to it same problem encounter in Enemy class

Comment: It is not possible to get CS1721 with one interface and one concrete class. I tried to recreate your problem and tried many possibilities. Yet, it is not possible to get this error. IDamageble shouldn't act as a concrete class, remove everything and recreate the same files, please.

Comment: Can you show us the `Enemy` code?